# Where does asp.net mvc text box input value is taken?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost/products/AddFeature?code=SMW
```

in the controller action, I create a model and set the

```
model.Code = "123112".
```

The View has this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code)
```

the final rendered html always shows "SMW" as the value.

Is this a bug where the query string value overrides the assigned value ? 
Does anyone got same results or I need some coffee ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the model state before returning your view. Be sure that you haven't missed some model error before you do that.  The helpers use the [ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.aspx), then the models for their values.

```
ModelState.Clear();
```